# How do I manage the imports in Angular correctly?

Tags: angular, csv, highcharts, angular-data

I am trying to import the Data Modules into Angular for reading CSV in highcharts like this:

```
import * as HighchartsMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import * as HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
import * as HighchartsData from "highcharts/modules/data";

HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);
HighchartsData(Highcharts);
```

However, when doing this I get following Error:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type
>   'typeof
>   import("angular-highcharts/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts-more")'
>   has no compatible call signatures

The other things I tried was doing the imports like this:

```
import HC_data from 'highcharts/modules/data';
let Boost = require('highcharts/modules/boost');
let noData = require('highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display');
let More = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
Boost(Highcharts);
noData(Highcharts);
More(Highcharts);
noData(Highcharts);
HC_data(Highcharts);
```

In this case, i don't get an error but the highcharts will just show:

> no data to display

whenever I try something like this in the chart settings:

```
data: {
   csv: csvFile
},
```

What am i doing wrong? how can i correctly import the data module? or how can i show csv data in highcharts correctly?

Comment: Your importing looks good. Check this example with data from csv: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-f14bh

Comment: That's where I have a lot of my code from. It doesn't work sadly

Comment: Could you reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following method .

```
import {HC_data} from 'highcharts/modules/data';
import {Boost} from 'highcharts/modules/boost';
import {noData} from 'highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display';
import  {More} from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
Boost(Highcharts);
noData(Highcharts);
More(Highcharts);
noData(Highcharts);
HC_data(Highcharts);
```

Try out this code .

Comment: this results in a warning message: Module '"../../../node_modules/highcharts/modules/data"' has no exported member 'HC_data'